# How to associate a printer driver

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I installed 22.04.3 LTS Ubuntu about 2 days ago and am green as possible with it. I have manged to get my printer - Epson WF-2510 into the printers list as well as  well as a CUPS_BRF printer.

According to https://www.openprinting.org/printer/Epson/Epson-WF-2010_Series a driver which will work is a  epson-201211w driver. I have no idea how to install that driver and get the WF-2510 to use it. Any help would be appreciated.

Alternative it it would be simpler i would be happy to use the CUPs - how would I do that?.

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the CUPS (Common Unix Printing Sysyem) GUI by pointing your browser  to `http://localhost:631`.

You can detect, add, and manage printers from the `Admin` tab, and deal with individual printers from the `Printers` tab. You can set the system default printer.

From the command line,

`lpstat -t`

will show the total state of the printing system.

Comment: Hi , Thank you for your assistance. It didn't solve the problem totally but put me on the right track. Ihttps://www.marksayson.com/blog/epson-configuring-printers-on-linux/ used the information you gave combined with this. The problem is now solved so thank you again